# Win form not opening after deploying Outlook VSTO Addin?

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin

I have deployed an Outlook Add-in using Visual Studio Installer project(followed [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/deploying-a-vsto-solution-by-using-windows-installer?view=vs-2019) link) with C#.

The setup is getting installed correctly(.msi) and I am able to see it inside Options -> Add-in, also the ribbon is visible with the controls.(It's a winform)

Unfortunately, **when I hit the button(inside Ribbon), nothing happens.**

Code in Ribbon.cs:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
{
    Form1 formObj = new Form1();

    formObj.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog;

    formObj.MaximizeBox = false;

    formObj.MinimizeBox = false;

    formObj.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;

    //formObj.ShowDialog();
    formObj.Show();
}
```

The code is working fine while debugging solution.

I searched but found nothing related. What can be the issue here or I am missing something?

Regards,
Ank

Comment: Try to log the routine eg. call stuff like `File.AppendAllText("C:\\test.txt", "Button Click");`

Comment: Thanks, this helped me in getting the correct issue.

Comment: FYI you can mark your own answer as accepted.

Comment: Not getting any option like that :(

Comment: Seems like you have to wait 48 hours before you can do that. Didn't know that. - https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the issue here.

Actually I have a dependency for win form(Materialskin.dll), which was excluded from the detected dependecies(inside setup project), as mentioned in the tutorial.

I changed the exclude property value to false only for Materialskin.dll and rebuild the solution.

After successful installation of created msi package, the Addin is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably your form is displayed behind the Outlook window. To get it visible on top of Outlook windows you must specify the parent window handle. You can retrieve it by casting the Outlook window instance like Explorer or Inspector to the IOLEWindow interface and using the [IOleWindow::GetWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oleidl/nf-oleidl-iolewindow-getwindow) method which retrieves a handle to one of the windows participating in in-place activation (frame, document, parent, or in-place object window).

The [Show](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.show?view=netcore-3.1) or `ShowDialog` method accepts an instance of the [IWin32Window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.iwin32window?view=netcore-3.1) interface which represents your parent window handle.

```
 /// <summary>
 /// Implemented and used by containers and objects to obtain window handles 
 /// and manage context-sensitive help.
 /// </summary>
 /// <remarks>
 /// The IOleWindow interface provides methods that allow an application to obtain  
 /// the handle to the various windows that participate in in-place activation, 
 /// and also to enter and exit context-sensitive help mode.
 /// </remarks>
 [ComImport]
 [Guid("00000114-0000-0000-C000-000000000046")]
 [InterfaceType (ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
 public interface IOleWindow
 {
     /// <summary>
     /// Returns the window handle to one of the windows participating in in-place activation 
     /// (frame, document, parent, or in-place object window).
     /// </summary>
     /// <param name="phwnd">Pointer to where to return the window handle.</param>
     void GetWindow (out IntPtr phwnd) ;

     /// <summary>
     /// Determines whether context-sensitive help mode should be entered during an 
     /// in-place activation session.
     /// </summary>
     /// <param name="fEnterMode"><c>true</c> if help mode should be entered; 
     /// <c>false</c> if it should be exited.</param>
     void ContextSensitiveHelp ([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)] bool fEnterMode) ;
 }

 public IWin32Window  getWindowHandle()
 {
        dynamic activeWindow = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWindow();
        IOleWindow win = activeWindow as IOleWindow;
        window = win.GetWindow();        
        IWin32Window wind = Control.FromHandle(window);

        return wind;
 }

// and pass it to the Show method

form.Show(getWindowHandle());
```